# Which scope(s) should I use to ask GitHub for permission to read public profile data + private email addresses?

Tags: rest, github, github-api

According to [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes), the default scope is read-only access to public profile data, but you have to specify the scope `user:email` to get private email addresses. How can I get both? I can't see any explicit parameter to get public profile data as well as email addresses (`user:email`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my testing, even though the documentation doesn't say so explicitly, the `user:email` scope gives read access to the public parts of the user profile as well.